# Is inner product a geodesically convex/concave function in $SO(3)$?

Tags: convex-analysis, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Recently I'm dealing with the 3D rotation group $SO(3)$, which is also a manifold. I'm new to Manifold, so I'm a little bit confused about geodesically convex functions.

The $SO(3)$ are rotation matrices, so it naturally embeds into $\mathbb{R}^9$. In Euclidean space, the function $$f(X) = Tr(A^TX)\quad X\in SO(3)$$ for some matrix $A$ is affine in $X$, so it's concave and convex at the same time.

But we can also see this $f$ as a function from the manifold $SO(3)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. But on Riemannian manifolds, we can only define geodesically convex, which is defined to be the convexity on its geodesic. So I am wondering if this $f$ is geodesically convex/concave? If so how can we prove this? Or if not, are there any easily understood ways to show?

I have tried to follow the definition of [geodesically convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) and using [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). But the final form seems to be too complicated for me to reach the conclusion. Any guides or insights will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

***Beware:** This is somewhat hand-wavy, and done mostly on-screen with hardly any proof-reading, so there's a huge chance I've made a number of misprints and possibly more critical errors!*

As far as I can tell, a geodesic $X_t$ in $SO(3)$ can always be written on the form
$$X_t = X_0\cdot\exp(tR)$$
where $R=-R^T$ is the direction and speed of rotation.

We are looking at $\text{tr}(AX_t)=\text{tr}[AX_0\cdot\exp(tR)]$, and $\exp(tR)$ is a constant speed rotation which is what makes the curve $X_t$ a geodesic. We define
$$
\exp(M)
=I+M+\frac{M^2}{2!}+\frac{M^3}{3!}+\cdots
=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(I+\frac{M}{n}\right)^n
$$
which will come in handy later.

We can always choose a basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$ so that the rotation is in the $e_1, e_2$ plane. If the rotation speed is $\omega$, that makes
$$
\exp(tR)
= \exp\left[\begin{matrix}
0&t\omega&0\\
-t\omega&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix}
\cos(t\omega)&\sin(t\omega)&0\\
-\sin(t\omega)&\cos(t\omega)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
which we can then plug into the trace:
$$
\text{tr}(AX_t)
= \text{tr}\left(AX_0\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
\cos(t\omega)&\sin(t\omega)&0\\
-\sin(t\omega)&\cos(t\omega)&0\\
0&0&1
\end{matrix}\right]\right)
= a + b\,\cos(t\omega) + c\,\sin(t\omega)
$$
where $a,b,c$ are linear in the coefficients of $AX_0$. Of course, we also have to express $A$ and $X_0$ in the $e_1,e_2,e_3$ basis.

So now we must determine when this expression is convex or concave in $t$.

The answer to that is simply that it is concave whenever $\text{tr}(AX_t)\ge a$ and convex whenever $\text{tr}(AX_t)\le a$. That's just because $\cos$ (or $\sin$) is concave when it is positive and convex when it is negative as we could have rewritten $\text{tr}(AX_t) = a + d\,\cos(t\omega - \nu)$ for $b=d\,\cos\nu$, $c=d\sin\nu$.

For the function $X\mapsto\text{tr}(AX)$ to be geodesically convex (or concave) at a point $X_0\in SO(3)$ is the same as saying that all geodesics passing through $X_0$ are convex (or concave) there. That is, $\text{tr}[AX_0\cdot\exp(tR)]$ is convex (or concave) at $t=0$ for all $R=-R^T$. We can check that by taking the second derivative at $t=0$, which is $\text{tr}(A X_0 R^2)$.

So $X\mapsto\text{tr}(AX)$ is convex (or concave) at $X=X_0$ if $\text{tr}(A X_0 R^2)\ge0$ (or $\le 0$) for all skew-symmetric matrices $R=-R^T$. This will be the case if $AX_0$ is negative definite (or positive definite), but the criterion can be relaxed somewhat.

If $R$ represents rotation an angle $\omega$ around a unit vector $u$, then $-R^2 = RR^T = \omega^2\cdot(I-u^Tu)$. Using this, the criterion $\text{tr}(A X_0 R^2)\ge0$ (or $\le 0$) can be rewritten
$u A X_0 u^T\ge\text{tr}(A X_0)$ (or $\le$).

Thus, $X\mapsto\text{tr}(AX)$ is convex (or concave) at $X=X_0$ if $u A X_0 u^T\ge\text{tr}(A X_0)$ (or $\le$) for all unit vectors $u$.

If $A X_0$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1\le\lambda_2\le\lambda_3$, then $\text{tr}(A X_0)=\sum_i \lambda_i$, while $\lambda_1\le u A X_0 u^T\le\lambda_3$ for unit vectors $u$ with either equality obtainable by entering the corresponding eigenvector as $u$. Thus, we can express the criterion in terms of the eigenvalues:
$$
X\mapsto\text{tr}(A X)\quad
\begin{cases}
\text{is convex at $X=X_0$ if}\quad
\lambda_1\ge\text{tr}(A X_0) \iff \lambda_2+\lambda_3\le 0;
\\
\text{is concave at $X=X_0$ if}\quad
\lambda_3\le\text{tr}(A X_0) \iff \lambda_1+\lambda_2\ge 0;
\\
\text{otherwise, it is convex in some directions, concave in other.}
\end{cases}
$$